# How to SSH into a host without starting byobu

Tags: byobu

My zsh shell automatically starts byobu. The host in question has a 1m loadavg of 300 at the moment (time ssh host time uptime returns in 50 seconds from local, with 3 seconds spent remotely).

Starting byobu takes an inordinate amount of time. I'd like to start without byobu. Can I pass some environment variable to cancel byobu startup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use the LC_BYOBU=0 environment variable:

```
LC_BYOBU=0 ssh user@hostname
```

Alternatively, you can asl do this:

```
ssh -t user@hostname zsh
```

or

```
ssh -t user@hostname bash
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Answer (score 1):

As found in `/usr/bin/byobu-launch`:

```
# 1) Prevent recursion, and multiple sourcing of profiles with the BYOBU_SOURCED_PROFILE environment variable.
# 2) Respect environment variables (LC_BYOBU and BYOBU_DISABLE) passable over SSH to disable
#    Byobu launch.  This puts that configurability on the SSH client,
#    in addition to the server.
#    To use over SSH, your /etc/ssh/sshd_config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config
#    must pass this variable with AcceptEnv and SendEnv.
#    Note that LC_* are passed by default on Debian/Ubuntu, we'll optionally
#    support LC_BYOBU=0
#    And in your local bashrc:
#      $HOME/.bashrc:  export LC_BYOBU=0
#    or edit your sshd_config, ssh_config, and set:
#      $HOME/.bashrc:  export BYOBU_DISABLE=1
```